# Where to put view initialization in nibless AppKit project?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I'm currently working on a nibless AppKit project and I was wondering where it would be appropriate to initialize views other than the main window. Here is what I have now:

main.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

    [application setDelegate:applicationDelegate];

    [application run];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And my AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSRect contentSize = NSMakeRect(200, 300, 300, 100);
    window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: contentSize styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
                                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                    defer:NO];
    window.title = @"NewWindow";
    window.level = NSModalPanelWindowLevel;
    return self;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
@end
```

If I want to now add subviews to my window such as buttons and panes, would I do all of that in the `init` method of my AppDelegate? Would I subclass NSWindow and change the init method there? Should I do all of it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to follow MVC architecture and create an `NSViewController` class for your custom view. You can perform view initialization in `-loadView` method.